# symfony : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: symfony

I just started learning symfony framework ,and I want to  start a server web for my first project and when I type the commande "**composer require server --dev**" I receive this error message, I've been searching for similar solutions for the same problem and i did not find anything. [the screenshot of error message is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuJ2C.png). Help Me Please !!

My **composer.json** file :

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.13",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.9",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.1",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because this bundle is deprecated, from the readme:

> CAUTION: this bundle is deprecated since Symfony 4.4. Instead, use the Symfony Local Web Server.

Use the [Symfony CLI](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cloud/getting-started) instead.